# Openshift abort PVC deletion stuck in terminating

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We deleted by mistake a PVC in OCP4. Luckly there is a finzlizer which is preventing it to be deleted.

The question is: how can we abort the termination and so the PVC status is back to ready/ok?

Comment: I'm not sure how the PVC status is back.. How about taking a snapshot instead?